# Google Drive API: Queries per x seconds per user

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth

The Google Drive API has a quota called `Queries per 100 seconds *per user*` - but what exactly is a user?
Is it per OAuth 2.0 client ID, or is it per source IP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As what stated in the [note](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/query-parameters):

> Note: Per-user quotas are always enforced by the Drive API. If the
>   quotaUser and userIp parameters are omitted, **the quota user is
>   determined by the access token in the request**.

Answer (score 0):

In general when we refer to the user, it is the "end user". So in the drive API it would be the user who has given access to your app. But the same user could have given drive access to 500 other apps. If all of those apps try to access the user's drive a the same time then this limit could be reached easily and each of the app developer may wonder what they did wrong as they may be just doing 1 qps. So this relates to the user's drive account.

Comment: Thanks, so if I understood you correctly: if I'm accessing my Google Drive from two different locations/PCs via API, it doesn't matter if I access it with two different OAuth 2.0 client IDs - they still share that 100 queries/sec since I'm the only "end user" for my drive?